# Не получается нажать кнопку на странице при помощи Selenium для java

Tags: java, selenium

Не получается нажать кнопку на странице при помощи Seleniume для java.
Мне надо нажать на кнопку в калькуляторе google.
у меня получилось зайти на страницу google.
В строке поиска набрать "Калькулятор", нажать Enter, при этом открывается калькулятор.
Пробую нажать на цифру "0", не получается. Вот примерный код:

```
 WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.className("div.PaQdxb.A2W7l"));
 element.click();
```

Выдаёт ошибку. Что я делаю не правильно?

Ошибку вот такую выдаёт:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke
> "pages.CalcPages.findZero()" because "tests.googleTests.calcPages" is
> null

Comment: Вы делаете неправильно то, что не говорите, какую ошибку *оно выдает*.

Comment: Ошибку вот такую выдаёт: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "pages.CalcPages.findZero()" because "tests.googleTests.calcPages" is null

Answer (score 0):

```java
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[.='0']"));
element.click();
```